# convert csv file to table in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I am using the csv library within ruby 1.9, and trying to follow the example for a table shown here:

[Link to faster_csv on github](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/blob/master/examples/csv_table.rb)

My code is as follows:

```
<% require 'csv' %>
<% table = CSV.parse("public/assets/file.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters =>   :symbol) %>

 <%= table %>
```

But the above returns a blank screen where I am expecting it to show the file.

Also when I try to view table[0].fields, I get the error

```
undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass
```

The following works when reading a csv file however:

```
<% b = CSV.read("public/assets/khq.csv") %>
<%= b %>
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly with the table example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1.9.2, Try

```
CSV.table("public/assets/file.csv")
```

or

```
CSV.read("public/assets/file.csv", :headers=>true, :conveters=>:numeric, :header_converters=>:symbol)
```

FYI, CSV.parse is for string, not for a file.
You may take a look at document here at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse

Comment: Please also make it sure your path is correct considering absolute path instead of relative path.